# Wunderlist API: Patch request of completed task works on http request , but not update on app

Tags: rest, http, request, wunderlist

I try to use the patch request to complete my task and I get a response for task completion, but it doesn't update on the wunderlist app. I did about 9 revision. I get a response that shows completion, but when I return to the app it shows no update. Here my response from the request:

```
{
"id": 3898040341,
"created_at": "2018-06-01T10:20:00.703Z",
"created_by_id": 24870738,
"created_by_request_id": "worker:w:w:recurring_task_creator:parent-3858561041",
"recurrence_type": "day",
"recurrence_count": 1,
"due_date": "2018-06-02",
"completed": true,
"completed_at": "2018-06-18T12:30:20.547Z",
"completed_by_id": 24870738,
"starred": false,
"list_id": 350926181,
"revision": 9,
"title": "Turn on computer",
"type": "task"
}
```

It says I completed it today, but the apps didn't update on either my phone, tablet, or completed.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figure it out. The id of the task changes everytime it is completed. This is for a recurring task. So I need to update the current request with a new ID.

Old request result with ID 3952832467

```
{
    "id": 3952832467,
    "created_at": "2018-06-19T11:42:13.366Z",
    "created_by_id": 24870738,
    "created_by_request_id": "worker:w:w:recurring_task_creator:parent-3949658004",
    "recurrence_type": "day",
    "recurrence_count": 1,
    "due_date": "2018-06-05",
    "completed": true,
    "completed_at": "2018-06-19T11:42:55.835Z",
    "completed_by_id": 24870738,
    "starred": false,
    "list_id": 350926181,
    "revision": 2,
    "title": "Turn on computer",
    "type": "task"
}
```

Same request result, but with no ID 3952834287:

```
{
    "id": 3952834287,
    "created_at": "2018-06-19T11:42:56.132Z",
    "created_by_id": 24870738,
    "created_by_request_id": "worker:w:w:recurring_task_creator:parent-3952832467",
    "recurrence_type": "day",
    "recurrence_count": 1,
    "due_date": "2018-06-06",
    "completed": true,
    "completed_at": "2018-06-19T14:52:28.644Z",
    "completed_by_id": 24870738,
    "starred": false,
    "list_id": 350926181,
    "revision": 2,
    "title": "Turn on computer",
    "type": "task"
}
```